# PDF download from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a page that when a user clicks a button, a PDF is dynamically generated and offered for them to download.

This is the code that's letting the user download the pdf:

```
// Omitted code that generates the pdf bytes

response.ContentType = "application/octetstream";
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
response.End();
```

On my machine and many others using a mixture of Chrome, IE 7/8/9b and Firefox, this is working as expected; the user clicks the button, the PDF gets downloaded.

On some instances of IE7, our users are reporting that they are getting an error message:

"Internet Explorer cannot download Publish.aspx from thesite.com

Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either not available or cannot be found. Please try again later".

Publish.aspx is the page that the button is residing on, so that page *is* available. IE should be downloading the pdf.

Is there anything that is wrong with the above code that could be causing this on certain machines? Or is it down to particular security / OS / browser settings?

EDIT:

These are the response headers from fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octetstream
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myPdf.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 12 Nov 2010 09:48:06 GMT
Content-Length: 45772
```

Comment: It would be nice to see all response headers.

Comment: Edited to include response headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very recently I bumped into the same error. In my case I was using https and no caching. It seems to be a security feature in IE to not download the file. From EricLaw's IEInternals:

> if a user tries to download* a file over a HTTPS connection, any response headers that prevent caching will cause the file download process to fail.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201040009/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx)

Comment: I was running into the same issue. Here's a workaround from the linked site: "Update Oct. 2010: I've conducted some further investigation of this issue, and found that (surprisingly) you CAN specify Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache and the download will work, but if you specify these directives in the opposite order, it will fail." I tried this and it worked. Reverse the cache-control headers.

Answer (score 3):

That's maybe because the correct mime type is `application/octet-stream`, not `application/octetstream`.

Comment: Although it may be an issue, this isn't what's causing his specific error. See Joop's answer.

Answer (score 2):

try using Response.OutputStream

```
filepath= Server.MapPath(filepath);
                FileStream strm = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                byte[] fileByte = new byte[strm.Length];
                int x = strm.Read(fileByte, 0, fileByte.Length);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", fileByte.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + filename);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.OutputStream.Write(fileByte, 0, fileByte.Length);
                Response.Flush();
                strm.Close();
```

and your content type must be ="application/pdf"

Comment: application/pdf will allow the browser to display the PDF, if there's a plugin configured to do that.  application/octet-stream should ask to download the file, regardless of plugin configuration.  (Personally, I don't like PDFs opening in the browser without asking to save.)

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas is correct that "octetstream" (without the dash) is not a known [MIME Type](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp).

I suggest using `application/pdf`.

Comment: By using `application/pdf` most browser will directly open the pdf file rather than ask the user about saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference if you use `response.TransmitFile` / `response.WriteFile`?

[TransmitFile (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28VS.80%29.aspx)
[WriteFile(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've corrected the content type to application/octet-stream and changed the caching.  It seems to be an IE + SSL issue, so I'll find out if it works when it's deployed later this evening.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Found in [google](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39141) solution of similar problem:

```
Response.AppendHeader('Expires', 'Sun, 17 Dec 1989 07:30:00 GMT');
```